# Use GPP as Ethernet device

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, ethernet

I've been trying to find to help in a little project I've been working on.
I want to connect my ARM board, to an x86 device with PCIe, and use socket API.
I have an ARM based board, which I'm connecting to a PC using PCIe, and I want the make the PC recognize it as an Ethernet device.
There's a lot of reference code and docs for the PC side, but I can't find anything to make the ARM "act" as an Ethernet, as the host side needs some parameters from the HW, such as MAC addresses, MTU etc...

So, what I'm asking:

1. Am I right in my assumptions, that once I'm able to provide the host with some Eth parameters, then the Linux on the host will populate an Ethernet device?
2. If 1 is yes, than what are the params?
3. Most importantly, I'm looking for doc or sources, so any lead would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: Can you share exact specification of the ARM board and let us know further on what exactly is being tried out. The manuals that came along with your ARM based board should have the related information.